# how can i remove the margin on top form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I want to remove the margin on top the form, so that it will have the same margin with the text on the left.

This is my code:

```
<div class="secound-top container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 col-xl-12">

  <h4 class="title"> Plain Page</h4>

    <form>

      <div class="input-group">

        <input class="search-text" type="text" name="name" placeholder="search for....">

          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i>Go</i></button>

          </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2Azd.png)

Comment: Remove either bootstrap 3 or 4 tag. Also add more CSS in the code snippet as I doubt this will show the problem

Comment: Am finding it difficult to add the css code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the error, I enclosed the form tag on a container div, then with a negative margin-top, the form went up:

There is the code:

```
<div class="container-fluid form">

    <form>



        <input class="search-text" type="text" name="name" placeholder="search 
         for....">

          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i>Go</i></button>

          </div>

           CSS
           .form{
          margin-top: -30px;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this into you CSS file or in the style tags:

```html
body{
    margin-top: 0px; 
    }
```